# MetaData of downloaded zipped file

Tags: python

```
url='http://www.test.com/test.zip'
z = zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(urllib.urlopen(url).read()))
z.extractall(path='D:')
```

I am writing above code to download a zipped file from a url and have downloaded and extracted all files from it to a specified drive and it is working fine.
Is there a way I can get meta data of all files extracted from z for example.
filenames,file sizes and file extenstions etc?

Comment: Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects), specifically `namelist()` and `infolist()`.

Comment: Thanks @SuperBiasedMan that worked perfectly.I was having hard time fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zipfile objects actually have built in tools for this that you can use without even extracting anything. `infolist` returns a list of [ZipInfo objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipinfo-objects) that you can read certain information out of, including full file name and uncompressed size.

```
import os

url='http://www.test.com/test.zip'
z = zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(urllib.urlopen(url).read()))
info = z.infolist()
data = []
for obj in info:
    name = os.path.splitext(obj.filename)
    data.append(name[0], name[1], obj.file_size)
```

I also used `os.path.splitext` just to separate out the file's name from its extension as you did ask for file type separately from the name.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a built-in way to do that using the `zipfile` module, however it is easily done using `os.path`:

```
import os

EXTRACT_PATH = "D:"

z= zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(urllib.urlopen(url).read()))
z.extractall(path=EXTRACT_PATH)
extracted_files = [os.path.join(EXTRACT_PATH, filename) for filename in z.namelist()]
for extracted_file in extracted_files:
    # All metadata operations here, such as:
    print os.path.getsize(extracted_file)
```